# Amazon ec2 Changing Time Zone Mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, datetime, amazon-ec2

I am posting this and I do understand that there are other posts like it, however, other solutions are not working for me.

When I try to run this on me Amazon ec2 server it gives me an error.

Command:

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
```

Error:

```
ln: cannot remove `/etc/localtime': Permission denied
```

I have seen similar posts with this being the easy solution, but... it isn't working. I am running and Ubuntu server on aws.amazon.com and have a Mac.

Can anyone provide a solution to my issue?

Sorry in advance if this is something stupid or dumb that I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using superuser;

`sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime`